# React Browserify Babel - Unexpected token error

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs

I'm attempting to bundle my dependencies using browserify via the command line.  The command completes without error - from what I can tell, but loading the page results in a 'Unexpected token <' error.

Here's the command I'm using:

```
browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] main.js -o bundle.js
```

main.js

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var $ = require('jQuery');
```

JSX:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var $ = require('jQuery');

class SideNav extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {items: new Array()};

}
componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"/json/sidenav.json",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({items: data});
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
render() {
     var items = [];
     this.state.items.forEach((item) => {
         items.push(<NavItem title={item.title} link={item.link} active={item.active} />);
     });
    return (
        <ul className="nav nav-sidebar">
        {items}
        </ul>
    );
  }

}
class NavItem extends React.Component{
    render() {
        var clazz = this.props.active ? 'active' : '';
        var link = this.props.active ? 
                <a href="#">{this.props.title} <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a> :
                <a href={this.props.link}>{this.props.title}</a>
        return (
            <li className={clazz}>{link}</li>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SideNav/>, 
    document.getElementById('sidenav')
);
```

Comment: I looks like the babel transformation of jsx isn't kicking in. Try searching for `<NavItem` in bundle.js to find out if that is the case.

Comment: No - NavItem is not in bundle.js

Comment: Ah, of course, it's been uglified. Try searching just for `<` in bundle.js and see if it's used anywhere that looks like JSX syntax.

Comment: It hasn't been uglified....   It looks like react and react dom are there

Comment: Ok, but did you find anything that looks like JSX in the bundle.js?

Comment: no nothing from the JSX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128361/discussion-between-arnehugo-and-matt-sloan).

Comment: My guess is you're getting a 404 or other error on your ajax call to "/json/sidenav.json".  "Unexpected token <" is exactly what you get when you try to parse HTML as JavaScript/JSON.  Check that your JSON file is being served up and received properly. Also check that you're not getting any 404's or other friendly error HTML returned from your ".js" files (e.g. if you don't have a route set up properly, you could get a friendly 404 message instead of your .js file)

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks to ArneHugo!  He realized that I was including the JSX in my .hmtl which meant it wasn't getting transpiled.  Moving it to main.js and then fixing a typo fixed the problem.